# Android: Can I have a mixed format text in TextView

Tags: android, text, formatting

I need to have a mixed format text in Android app
something like
"Hi **how** are *you*"
maybe even with different colors

is there a way to do it from the xml configuration of from the java code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `SpannableString` class from the java code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial here [Different Format Text](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html)